# Can a PCI Graphics card, and AGP be used together?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, pci, agp

The question pretty much says it all.

I use an old 845GBV board ( to-date reliant upon the integrated graphics processor ). All slots on the board are unused. Lately I've been thinking in terms changing it to a dual monitor so that I can use one console for documentation/help/sample code/whatever, the other one to play with code.

Assuming this board can handle a PCI GPU, can an AGP4x board coexist with a PCI GPU?

Comment: To answer your question, yes a PCI and a AGP card can both work in the same box. Can't answer any details about that specific model of motherboard though.

Comment: There was a [motherboard](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/K8N-Neo3.html) which marketed this as a feature, so I'm sure it works.

Comment: Interesting board. -- Link updated: http://www.msi.com/product/motherboard/K8N_Neo3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is a system specific block on this, it should work.

Comment: I don't get why you use old technology like this, but I agree with DaBear, it schould work.

Comment: @Michael - Scrimping on pennies, I am :D